# Pass list of WebElements in a parameter of a function and loop it using selenium c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, nunit

I have a common function to verify the element is present in the page as below

```
public EditorialMiscellaneousPages VerifyContent(element)
    {
        Boolean _element = element.Displayed;
        if(_element)
        {
            passTest = "Expected Content exists";
            Console.WriteLine(passTest);
        }
        else
        {
            failTest = "Expected Content do not exists";
            Console.WriteLine(failTest);
        }
        return new EditorialMiscellaneousPages(driver);
    }
```

The above code works fine if I am verifying only one element in a page. I can call the function "VerifyContent" everytime to check the content of the page. But if I want to verify 4 elements in page1, 3 elements in page 2, 7 elements in page 3 etc....
The above code doesn't work. In order to achieve that I might need to use List I believe and loop it. Can someone help me with that logic please?

Comment: You need to provide more info, showing the context in which this method is used. Ideally, show the test code, which does not work. Additionally, show or tell us where driver comes from and where in your tests it is initialized.

Comment: And please describe what "it doesn't work means". Are you getting an exception? If so, include the message and stack trace.

Comment: For example,

Page 1 : It has 2 header text
Page 2 : It has 5 header text
Page 3 : It has 9 header text

I need to verify if the text is present or not. If i use the above method i can verify only one header in Page 1, But i want to pass parameters say a list. Then how can i acheive that using the above common method...I know i need to make slight changes but i dont know i to make it